# How to use freelancer api for android app

Tags: android, freelancer.com-api

I am making an android app i want to add a feature that user can operate their freelancer account with my app. I searched that freelancer provides api but i don't know that how to use that api.

Some source to get stated and tutorials for how to use that are appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Freelancer API is `REST` webservice API type. For example `[link](http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/).

Firstly connect and download data from specific URI then parse it with JSON or XML parser.